# Conditional Calc of Time Distance While performing a Linq Query

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to perform the below query over a list of objects with a `StartTime` propertie. The problem is that sometimes `null` values can be founded.

So, how can I check if the value is `null` and if it is perform a random number between 2 values?

```
  var myOtherQuery = db.Table.Select(e=> e );

var myQuery = myOtherQuery.Select(e => new { e, TimeDistance = ((DateTime) e.StartTime - DateTimeNow).TotalMinutes });
```

**This is L2SQL**
**Some objects have null values in StartTime which results in a exception while trying to determinate the TimeDistance **

Comment: Where is the null value found ? Do you mean sometimes StartTime is null ? You can check for values in C# using the ?? operator

Comment: Is this LINQ to SQL, LINQ to Objects, Entity Framework, something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
var myQuery = myOtherQuery.Select(e => 
    new { E = e, 
          TimeDistance = ((e.StarTime.HasValue ? e.StartTime.Value : someOtherValue) - DateTime.Now).TotalMinutes 
    }
);
```

Or:

```
var myQuery = myOtherQuery.Select(e => 
    new { E = e, 
          TimeDistance = (e.StarTime.HasValue ? (e.StartTime.Value - DateTime.Now) : someOtherValue).TotalMinutes 
    }
);
```

Comment: It seems so, let me check! Thanks

Comment: There's a small problem with that kind of evaluation. Because i don't want someOtherValue to be subtracted with DateTime.Now. 

In other words, I want It to be the alternative result to the calc between (StartTime and DateTime.Now).TotalMinutes

Comment: Thanks, another thing i was wondering is if it was possible to call some NOTVOID function to fill the someOtherValue. And Yes, it is. :)